# How do I highlight using multiple faces with library `highlight.el`?

Tags: faces, highlighting

I want to highlight in multiple colors using `highlight.el`.

I'm trying to use:

`(highlight-regexp regexp1)`

followed by

`hlt-next-face`

But it seems to be consistently using the same face.  How do I get `highlight-regexp` to use a different face. I'd prefer to not keep track faces myself, just get it to use a new one, which `hlt-next-face` claims to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`highlight-regexp` is not part of library [Highlight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)). It's part of vanilla Emacs.  Functions and variables defined by library `highlight.el` use prefix `hlt-`.  Only library `highlight.el` lets you use `hlt-next-face`.

The main `highlight.el` command for highlighting regexp matches in the region (or the buffer) is **`hlt-highlight-regexp-region`**. Try that, instead of `highlight-regexp`.

Be aware too that vanilla command `highlight-regexp` works with `hi-lock-mode`, which means it works (only) with `font-lock-mode` turned on.

Features of library `highlight.el` can be used to highlight text whether or not font locking is on. To understand how to do this, see  [Interaction with Font Lock](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary#InteractionWithFontLock) for using `highlight.el` with and without `font-lock-mode` being on.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I need to specify a region. I'm using `point-min` and `point-max` for this `(hlt-unhighlight-regexp-region (point-min) (point-max) 't)` and `(hlt-highlight-regexp-region (point-min) (point-max) "regexp")`
`

Comment: All of the args are optional. See function `hlt-region-or-buffer-limits` for how args `START` and `END` are defaulted.

Comment: Thanks. Presumably I need `START` and `END` if I want to specify the regular expression though?

Comment: Yes. But just use `nil` values for any such optional variables you want to have that default value.